# Is it possible to specify the size of the length and width of a plot separately?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

Is it possible to specify the size of the length and width of a general `Plot` output? Using `AspectRatio` changes both vertical and horizontal axes, but I want to enlarge the horizontal axis only (the vertical to remain the same).

Example. `ListPlot[{{1,1},{2,2},{3,3}},Frame-> True]`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With `AspectRatio->Full`, you can use a `ImageSize` setting of the form `ImageSize->{width,height}` to individually control both dimensions without the need to guess the aspect ratio:

```
ListPlot[
 {{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}},
 Frame -> True,
 AspectRatio -> Full,
 ImageSize -> {300, 100}
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Try to combine `ImageSize` with the `AspectRatio` like this:

```
Row[{ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, Frame -> True, 
   ImageSize -> 300, AspectRatio -> 1],
  ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 150, 
   AspectRatio -> 2.2]}]
ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}, Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 300, 
 AspectRatio -> 0.5]
```

with the following effect:

[image]

Have fun!

Answer (score 6):

You can experiment by commenting out the lines that change the aspect ratio.

```
Manipulate[
 ListPlot[{{1, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}}
  , Frame -> True
  , ImageSize -> {width, height}
  , AspectRatio -> ar
  ]
 , {{ar, 0.6}, 0.25, 2}
 , {{width, 500}, 200, 600}
 , {{height, 500}, 200, 600}
 , ContentSize -> {600, 600}
 ]
```